# Specializing a function from a variadic template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, specialization

Consider this illegal code:

```
template <int... Is>
struct Object {
    void foo() const;    
};

template <int... Js>
void Object<0, Js...>::foo() {/*Do whatever*/}
```

We want to specialize foo() when the first template parameter is 0, and let's say we want to specialize foo() as well if the second parameter is 3, and the third int is 1.  So the solution I found (not sure if its the best approach) is the following:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int...> struct Foo;

template <int... Is>
struct Object {
    int ID;  // This member is just to illustrate the case when 'this' is needed in foo().
    friend struct Foo<Is...>;
    void foo() const {Foo<Is...>::execute(this);}  // Pass 'this' in case it is needed.
};

template <int... Is>
struct Foo<0, Is...> {
    static void execute (const Object<0, Is...>* object) {std::cout << "First int = 0, ID = " << object->ID << ".\n";}
};

template <int N, int... Is>
struct Foo<N, 3, Is...> {
    static void execute (const Object<N, 3, Is...>* object) {std::cout << "Second int = 3, ID = " << object->ID << ".\n";}
};

template <int M, int N, int... Is>
struct Foo<M, N, 1, Is...> {
    static void execute (const Object<M, N, 1, Is...>* object) {std::cout << "Third int = 1, ID = " << object->ID << ".\n";}
};


int main() {
    Object<0,5,8,2>{4}.foo();
    Object<4,3,2,5,3>{2}.foo();
    Object<4,2,1>{0}.foo();
}
```

First of all, is this solution any good?  Next, the problem now arises if we try `Object<0,3,1,4>{8}.foo();` because the spec was not complete.  So let's say that the earliest matched specialized int will always take precedence.  So in this case `Object<0,3,1,4>{8}.foo();` should run the first specialization because of the 0, while `Object<9,3,1,4>{8}.foo();` shall run the second specialization because of the 3, and so forth.  How to enforce that rule?

Answer (score 1):

A comment and a hint.

The approach for me is OK. Since we do not have partial template specialization for functions that's all we have.

Then regarding `Object<0,3,1,4>{8}.foo()` this gives ambiguous partial specializations (on Clang 3.6). To solver this problem I ended up adding another partial specialization

```
template <int... Is>
struct Foo<0, 3, Is...> {
    static void execute (const Object<0, 3, Is...>* object) {std::cout << "First int = 0, second = 3, ID = " << object->ID << ".\n";}
};
```

Another possibility is mess with std::integer_sequence. I have to give up now, the following is not a solution, just an appetizer...

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <class S1, class S2>
struct seq_lt
{
    enum {value = 0} ;
} ;

template <int I1, int ...S1, int I2, int ...S2>
struct seq_lt<std::integer_sequence<int, I1, S1...>,
              std::integer_sequence<int, I2, S2...>>
{
    enum {value = (I1 < I2 ? 1 : 0)} ;
} ;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3> seq1 ;
    std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3> seq2 ;

    std::cout << "seq_lt " << seq_lt<decltype(seq1), decltype(seq2)>::value << std::endl ;
    std::cout << "seq_lt " << seq_lt<decltype(seq2), decltype(seq1)>::value << std::endl ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  But won't the number of such combinations explode when their are many independent specializations?  Isn't there a more generic way?

Comment: I am thinking about an alternative approach where the integer sequence is mapped to a type and you overload the call using that type. But the idea is not clear yet

Comment: Perhaps the mapped type could be of the form `MappedType<A,B>`, where `A` is the argument position and `B` is the int value in that position?  Then define the overloaded function?  You mean something like that?  How to map, say, the {5,3,1,4} array to the intended type `MappedType<1,3>`? (whereby `overloaded_function(MappedType<1,3>)` then calls up the second specialization?

Comment: `struct Map<Is...> {using type = (NthValue<0,Is...>::value == 0) ? MappedType<0,0> : NthValue<1,Is...>::value == 3) ? MappedType<1,3> : NthValue<2,Is...>::value == 1) ? MappedType<2,1> : ...  };`, where `NthValue<N,Is...>::value` gives the Nth value of `Is...`  Something like that (and all done during compile time)?

Comment: Well, my idea was mess with integer sequence (an in the 'appetizer'). But I have to leave now and moreover I can test it only with online compilers (requires C++14)

Comment: @ marom   Your mapping idea inspired me to come up with a satisfying solution, which I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest just using `if` statements. The compiler will probably optimize them away anyway (assuming you have optimization enabled).

In other words, just do something like this:

```
template <int... Js>
void Object::foo() {
    std::array<int, sizeof...(Js)> args = {Js...}; // I _think_ this is the correct syntax to dump the parameter pack into an std::array.
    if(args.size() > 0 && args[0] == 0) {
        // First argument is 0, do whatever.
    } else {
        // It's not 0, do your other thing.
    }
}
```

You'll get pretty much the same effect, and your code will be quite a bit clearer.

Comment: @ celticminstrel  What if there are, say, 5 specializations for each argument position.  You still recommend using a big chain of if-statements?

Comment: I think even then it's likely to be clearer. However, I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, so I could be wrong. You could probably whip up a utility function (and declare it `constexpr`, if possible) which succinctly compares the parameter pack to any list of integers as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

This solution was inspired by Marom's second suggestion, and also inspired partly by celticminstrel's solution too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t, typename T, T...> struct NthValue;

template <typename T, T First, T... Rest>
struct NthValue<0, T, First, Rest...> : std::integral_constant<T, First> {};

template <std::size_t N, typename T, T First, T... Rest>
struct NthValue<N, T, First, Rest...> : NthValue<N - 1, T, Rest...> {};

template <int... Is>
struct Object {
    void foo() const {fooHelper (typename Map<Is...>::type{});}
private:
    template <int...> struct Map;
    template <int, int> struct MappedType {};
    struct Default {};
    void fooHelper (const MappedType<0,0>&) const {std::cout << "First int = 0.\n";}
    void fooHelper (const MappedType<1,3>&) const {std::cout << "Second int = 3.\n";}
    void fooHelper (const MappedType<2,1>&) const {std::cout << "Third int = 1.\n";}
    void fooHelper (const Default&) const {std::cout << "Default case.\n";}
};

template <int... Ns>
template <int... Is>
struct Object<Ns...>::Map {
    using type = typename std::conditional<NthValue<0, int, Is...>::value == 0,
        MappedType<0,0>, 
        typename std::conditional<NthValue<1, int, Is...>::value == 3,
            MappedType<1,3>,
            typename std::conditional<NthValue<2, int, Is...>::value == 1,
                MappedType<2,1>,
                Default
            >::type
        >::type
    >::type;
};

int main() {
    Object<0,5,8,2>().foo();  // First int = 0.
    Object<4,3,2,5,3>().foo();  // Second int = 3.
    Object<4,2,1>().foo();  // Third int = 1.
    Object<0,3,1,4>().foo();  // First int = 0.
    Object<9,3,1,4>().foo();  // Second int = 3.
    Object<9,9,9>().foo();  // Default case.
}
```

There is also no run-time overhead.

Comment: @ marom    I don't know if `template <int...> struct Map` should be inside the `Object<Is...>` class or outside of it though, and whether there is more memory footprint (or even compile-time overhead) by having it inside.  But there is apparently no reason for any other class to know about it.

Comment: Keep it inside...unless you can come up with something more general that deserves a stand-alone rights...

Comment: I'm curious. What part of this was inspired by my answer?

Comment: @ celticminstrel   Your nested if-statements.  My nested std::conditional templates is like a compile-time version of your run-time if-statements.